# how handle home folders with dual-boot (Catalina and BigSur)?

Tags: catalina, big-sur, dual-boot

I am happily running Catalina (on a Macbook Air 2017) and am tempted to upgrade to BigSur, but I'm a little leery of breaking apps, particularly Arduino IDE (which appears problematic, from the little searching I've done).  So I want to make the system dual-boot - my existing Catalina installation, and BigSur (or perhaps Monterey) - and live with the new OS for awhile before I commit.

There are numerous articles describing the process, in brief: use Disk Utility to add a new volume, download the appropriate installer, and install the new OS on the new volume.   But beyond that ?

It seems there are two ways to go:

1. Use Migration Assistant to import everything (apps, home folders, other files) to the new BigSur volume, thus two completely independent systems.
2. Use SystemPrefs -> Users&Groups "advanced" to point the home folder (when logged into BigSur) to the Catalina volume.

It seems each path has advantages and disadvantages and I'm not sure which to do.  #1 has the disadvantage that there's two copies of user data, thus the issue of keeping in sync - probably best achieved by only modifying files in one.  But #2 has the disadvantage that certain files (e.g. ~user/Library) may need to be different for the new OS (I'm pretty sure that's the case for Arduino IDE).

How should I slice this cake ?

As requested below, here is the current state of my disk:

```
% diskutil list internal
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *240.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         239.8 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +239.8 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume MacHD - Data            88.3 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 91.1 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                529.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      4.3 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume MacHD                   11.2 GB    disk1s5
```

After installing Big Sur ...

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *240.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         120.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk2⁩         119.8 GB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +120.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨MacHD - Data⁩            84.9 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 91.1 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                529.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨MacHD⁩                   11.2 GB    disk1s5

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +119.8 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s3
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨BigSur⁩                  67.3 GB    disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 287.6 MB   disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                625.7 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      1.1 MB     disk2s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Big Sur⁩                 15.3 GB    disk2s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.3 GB    disk2s5s1
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: AFAIK uses my dad Arduino IDE without problems on BigSur and unless I'm dreaming I have actually used it on BigSur with VSCode and Arduino extensions. Not sure if he has already upgraded to Monterey yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I advise you to separate the 2 systems.

Indeed if you access Catalina data from a higher system, you run the risk of not being able to access it from Catalina, the compatibility between systems is always upward and rarely downward.

Then I advise you to create a new container for BS or Monterey so as not to mix up the systems.

When you have tested the new system and if everything is ok, it's easy to clone the new system in place of the old one and free up unused disk space.

Comment: So a new container as opposed to merely a new volume ?   How does a new volume (within the same container), which most advise to do it this way, allow the systems to get mixed up ?

Comment: Because firstly you will only have one Recovery volume (the last installed)  common to the 2 systems and secondly you will gain very little disk space and the risk is great if you share the data between the 2 systems. This is just my point of view, then the choice is yours. Personally I always separate different systems into different containers.

Comment: So I'd do this (in Disk Utility) by highlighting the top level of my disk, then clicking the "Partition" button, and then selecting "partition" instead of "add volume" ?

Comment: Personally, I do that from the terminal, diskutil command. Can you add to your initial question the results (in text mode) of the command `diskutil list internal`

Comment: It is done now.

Comment: What size would you give to the new container? 100g

Comment: Disk is 240GB, so if I'm going to totally duplicate the system, I guess it should be 120GB.

Comment: Ok. You can first delete Snapshots :  `tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 99999999999 4` then resize the system container and add the new container named Big Sur : `diskutil ap resizecontainer disk1 120g apfs "Big Sur" 0b`

Comment: Why is this better than doing it in diskutil ?

Comment: I prefer the command line because it's more efficient and clearer than disk utility.

Comment: Ok, I did it, will temporarily place 'diskutil list' output into OP (won't fit in comment) - tell me if it looks right.   Shouldn't I be seeing BigSur and BigSur-HD volumes in disk2 ?

Comment: That's right. ;-) When you install BS all will be created.

Comment: Ok, all seems to be working, thanks.     When I'm happy with new OS (BigSur), how do I get rid of Catalina and free up that disk space ?   You mentoned cloning in answer.   Can't I simply delete the Catalina container and resize the BigSur one to use the entire disk ?

Comment: Uh @Jean_JD , things working fairly well, but some screwy stuff with volume names.   See end of OP for latest 'diskutil list' output.   And screenshot of DiskUtility sidebar, which also is a little screwy (one of the BigSurs is greyed out).

Comment: Also see add'l image (at bottom) of OP which is screen-grab of SystemInformation.  It seems to think the Big Sur system is a disk2s5s1, which is shown as a "snapshot" in the diskutil output.   This worries me.

Comment: Your BigSur Data volume has not good name. You can do `sudo diskutil rename "Big Sur - Data"  disk2s1` . On Big Sur and Monterey the boot System Volume is a Snapshot who duplicate the System Volume  Big Sur. It's normal. If you want more informations on the system structure you can see this excellent site : https://eclecticlight.co/2021/01/13/big-sur-boot-volume-layout/